# Do you have an idea to improve my getRange() function in Swift?

Tags: swift, function, swiftui

I have a function `getRange()` that works very well with simple cases like `Car(rent: [])`, `Car(rent: [.Monday])` or `Car(rent: [.Monday, .Tuesday])`.

```
import SwiftUI

enum Days {
    case Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday
}

struct Car: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let rent: [Days]
}

let cars = [
    Car(rent: [.Monday, .Tuesday])
]

struct ChildView: View {
    let car = cars[0]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(getRange())
        }
    }

    private func getRange() -> String {
        guard !car.rent.isEmpty else { return "Empty" }
        let firstMonth = car.rent.first!
        let lastMonth = car.rent.last!

        guard firstMonth != lastMonth else { return "\(firstMonth)" }
        return "\(firstMonth) to \(lastMonth)"
    }
}
```

But with a case like `Car(rent: [.Monday, .Tuesday, .Saturday, .Sunday])` the function doesn't work as expected.

I could resolve the problem with a simple update, starting with:

```
struct Car: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let rentMain: [Days]
    let rentOptional: [Days]
}
```

But my "database" is very huge and I would prefer to not update it.

So I wonder if you have an idea to make it works with cases like below (by working with the function)?

```
Car(rent: [.Monday, .Tuesday, .Saturday, .Sunday])
// Possible output: Monday to Tuesday, Saturday to Sunday
// Possible output: Monday to Tuesday and others
// Possible output: Monday to Tuesday
Car(rent: [.Monday, .Saturday, .Sunday])
// Possible output: Monday, Saturday to Sunday
// Possible output: Monday and others
// Possible output: Monday
```

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: I'm not clear if there is a desired output in a case as:
`let cars = [
    Car(rent: [.Monday, .Tuesday, .Wednesday, .Saturday, .Sunday])
]`

Comment: Can you rent a car from Saturday to Monday? And what if you want to rent it for more than a week?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Saturday to Monday could be a possible output even if I would prefer to keep the right order. I'm actually using a year calendar with months but for the example I simplified it with weekdays because it doesn't matter. Also, I'm using this array for another view that's why I would prefer to not update the it. But I'm not against showing only the first group of 2 (if there're 2 groups as well).

Answer (score 1):

This is a suggestion taking advantage of `IndexSet` which can be parsed in ranges.

The code creates an index set from the enum indices in the `Days` array, then it parses the ranges and returns the string formatted by a `ListFormatter`

```
enum Days: String, CaseIterable, CustomStringConvertible {
    case monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday
    
    var index : Int {
        Self.allCases.firstIndex(of: self)!
    }
    
    var description : String {
        self.rawValue.capitalized
    }
    
    static func range(of days: [Days]) -> String {
        var result = [String]()
        let indexSet = IndexSet(days.map(\.index))
        let weekdays = Self.allCases.map(\.description)
        for aRange in indexSet.rangeView {
            if aRange.count == 1 {
                result.append(weekdays[aRange.startIndex])
            } else {
                let start = weekdays[aRange.startIndex]
                let end = weekdays[aRange.endIndex - 1]
                result.append("\(start) to \(end)")
            }
        }
        let formatter = ListFormatter()
        return formatter.string(from: result)!
    }
}

let days : [Days] = [.monday, .wednesday, .thursday, .friday, .sunday]
print(Days.range(of: days)) // Monday, Wednesday to Friday, and Sunday
```

Comment: This could be what I was looking for but in a more complicated way. Haha! I'll play with it and see if I can make it works with my localized stuffs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the signature of the function, maybe this can be help:

```
import SwiftUI

enum Days {
    case Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday
}

struct Car: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let rent: [Days]
}

let cars = [
    Car(rent: [.Monday, .Saturday, .Sunday])
]

struct ChildView: View {
    let car = cars[0]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(getRange(days: car.rent))
        }
    }

    private func getRange(days: [Days]) -> String {
        if days.isEmpty { return "Empty" }
        if days.count == 2 {
            return "\(days[0]) to \(days[1])"
        }
        
        if days.count == 1 {
            return "\(days[0])"
        }
        
        if days.count % 2 == 0 {
            return getRange(days: Array(days[0...1])) + ", " + getRange(days: Array(days[2..<days.count]))
        }
        
        return getRange(days: [days[0]]) + ", " + getRange(days: Array(days[1..<days.count]))
    }
}
```

But is only an idea and I need more specific requirements of desired output.

Comment: I'm not sure that item count checking is really praticable. I was thinking more in terms of groups: 1 group (Monday, Thuesday) or 2 groups (Monday, Thuesday + Saturday, Sunday). But thanks, I'll try this out.